# security of NSUserDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm working with one of my first iPhone apps. I have made simple login for the users. I want to store variable in NSUserDefaults which will keep track of if user is logged in. If user is logged in than it will be 1, otherwise it will be 0. And of course in other variable user username.

My question is: Is NSUserDefaults secure for keeping information like that? Is there any way in which somebody or user could manipulate with this variables and login without knowing password?

Comment: thanks for the link, I have not found it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need security you should use Key Chains. It encodes values and is best way to save some security information. One thing that you should know is that you should not store there a lot of data as this storage is related to whole device not just to your application, so if your application will be deleted, stored data still will be alive. For example using User Defaults stored data would immediately become deleted(same with using Core Data).

Comment: If I store string and bool in NSUserDefaults, what is the way that someone could change value of these variables or even read them?

Comment: Than only your application can read them, as only it will have needed key to decode this values into valid data.

Comment: As well you can easily change them inside of your application. There is a lot of pods that make work with Key Chains really easy.

Comment: Isn't that good thing of NSUserDefaults that only my application can read my data? And, if I am right, if I store some sensible data in Key Chains, other applications can get/read them?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is not safe storage and professional can easily get it.
KeyChain is safe storage and only your application can read it and nothing else.

Comment: Oh, I got it totally wrong. :) I'll Google it how KeyChain works. Thanks!

Comment: Just one more question: if I delete the app Key Chain will still be existing on device with stored values and NSUserDefaults will be deleted from device if I delete the app?

Comment: you can check KeychainSwift pod, or simply download this file that have necessary code inside 
https://github.com/VolodymyrKhmil/BBBLibs/blob/master/BBBSocials/KeyChainSwiftWrapper.swift

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sometimes developers saving data to keychains not to make it secure, but to receive it even  if application was deleted, not just between sessions.